# Data puller and data pusher in pod or job

Tags: kubernetes, pipeline

I am trying to write a data process unit in kubernetes.

For every process unit has a quite similar workflow:

1. Puller pull data from object storage and mount an `/input` volume to container
2. Processor run the code to process data in volume and output data to `/output` volume
3. Pusher push data in `/output` volume to object storage again

So every pod or job must have a container as data pusher and data puller which is mentioned in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/) by shared volume. But how can i make the process as pull -> process -> push sequence?

Right now I can use volume share way to communication to make it work: first I can let puller start working and let data processor wait until it find a pull-finished.txt created. Then let the pusher start working when it find a process-finished.txt created. But this may have to force the data process container FROM some image or use some specific entrypoint which is not what I want. Is there a more elegant way to make this work?

Comment: Hi, Afaik, you could use init container to do these tasks. Besides it could be synchronized in a pod. here is the link of it [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but it has the information you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568337/kubernetes-processing-an-unlimited-number-of-work-items/49619517#49619517

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments by [Suresh Vishnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8803619/suresh-vishnoi) and [Janos Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371954/janos-lenart), the best approach is to use [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) for processing data from queue or input volume, and [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to have sequential steps to process the data.

Here is a good example of using init-containers from Kubernetes documentation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done;']
  - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup mydb; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done;']
```

Another good example you can find in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619517/9521610) provided by [Janos Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371954/janos-lenart)

Comment: So the containers part is just a notifier to say that all job is done. I have to use initContainers to make sure all jobs run in sequence?