# Is there a way to schedule docker containers to run with respect to one another?

Tags: python, bash, docker, kubernetes

I'm creating microservices using Docker Containers.

Initially, I run one Docker container and it provides me with some output that I need as input for a second docker container.

So the flow of steps would be:

1. Run Docker container;
2. Get output;
3. Trigger running of second Docker container with previous output.

I have looked into Kubernetes, cloud functions and pub/sub on Google Cloud. Though I would like to run this locally first.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution, my processes are more like scripts than web-based applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking from a auto-devops point of view, you can try utilizing `kubectl wait` command for this.

- Prepare yaml files for each of the containers (eg pod, deployment or statefulset)
- Write a shell script, running `kubectl apply -f` on the files.
- Use `kubectl wait` and `jsonpath` to pass info from prvious pods to the next, once it's in the ready / RUNNING state.

Find the detailed docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Kubernetes Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/). It might do the trick, although Kubernetes was not really made for running scripts in sequence and sharing dependencies between containers.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713573/how-to-run-containers-sequentially-as-a-kubernetes-job) is similar to what you need. One tool mentioned that intrigued me was [brigade](https://github.com/brigadecore/brigade/).