# How to run jobs sequentially by using Kubernetes and Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jobs

I want to schedule three sequential tasks using Kubernetes. these three tasks are:

1- download a file from a URL

2- process the file

3- Put the file in a web server (The server must be configured and some modules must be installed on it first)

I think I can do this using [Kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/), but I did not find an example of doing such tasks.

In Addition, I do not know how to first configure the web server before using it. Is it possible to create a Docker image from the server, configure it and finally get a snapshot from it?

EDIT:
As the first step, I just want to create a job for downloading a file. I could not find any sample for that; how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run containers sequentially as a Kubernetes job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713573/how-to-run-containers-sequentially-as-a-kubernetes-job)

Comment: @VasilyAngapov: I saw that topic but my goal is two parts: I do not know is it possible to use configured docker images in Kubernetes yaml files; and I do not know what is the best practice for my scenarion, e.g. using pods, jobs, docker images how must be used.

Comment: Kubernetes does not have builtin logic for sequential jobs. The most voted answer from the link I gave with initContainers is I believe the best possible way. It's a bit hacky and dirty but it will work.

Comment: Job queues like RabbitMQ also fit well in this space.  (Run RabbitMQ in a StatefulSet with a PersistentVolumeClaim, and run workers via a scalable Deployment, and don't use Jobs at all.)

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion the most efficient and great solution nowadays is still use [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use).

InitContainers is the best tool to handle your task in current situation.
Use [example provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880653/9929015) and implement all your tasks as initContainers.

About configuring web-server and further container usage:
There are a lot of articles that provide step-by-step instruction on how to create own Docker image.
I can recommend you use as an example [Steps To Build Apache Web Server Docker Image](https://medium.com/@vi1996ash/steps-to-build-apache-web-server-docker-image-1a2f21504a8e) article.