# k8s job with an unlimited/unknown number of work-items (completions)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a queue which filled (consistently) with work-item by one of my k8s pod.

I want to use k8s job to process each work item as I want each job to be handle by new pod as I want to use multiple container as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880653/963701), but jobs don't seem to support an infinite number of completions.

When I use `spec.completions: null` I got BackoffLimitExceeded.

Any Idea how to implement job without the need to specify the number of work item?

Is there alternative to job for implementing background worker in k8s ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to use Kubernetes resources in the way they have been designed: *Job* resources are one-off tasks that can ben triggered many times but they differ from the *background jobs* you're eager to implement.

If your application is *popping* jobs from a queue/backend, it's better to put in a Deployment with a `for` loop (YMMV according to programming language) and, eventually, scale it to down with another component if you don't want to allocate unused resources.

Another solution could be the specialization of each Job, using UUID as the name of the jobs and labelling them in order to group them: anyway, first suggestion of *using Kubernetes in the Kubernetes way* is strongly recommended.

Comment: using deployment with loop over queue is not a good solution for me as I want to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880653/963701 ( each work-item should be processed sequentially by different container)