# how to run docker compose as a cronjob

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 2 programs that need to be run periodically.

**simple_job_1.py:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

print("Starting job 1 ... ", datetime.now())
print("Doing stuff in job 1 for 20 seconds .........")
time.sleep(20)
print("Stopping job 1 ... ", datetime.now())
```

**simple_job_2.py:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

print("Starting job 2 ... ", datetime.now())
print("Doing stuff in job 2 for 5 seconds .........")
time.sleep(5)
print("Stopping job 2 ... ", datetime.now())
```

And I have created 2 docker images by building following Dockerfile's:

**For job1:**

```
FROM python:3

# Create a folder inside the container
RUN mkdir /home/TestProj

# Copy everything from the current folder in host to the dest folder in container
COPY . /home/TestProj

WORKDIR /home/TestProj

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "simple_job_1.py"]
```

**For job2:**

```
FROM python:3

# Create a folder inside the container
RUN mkdir /home/TestProj

# Copy everything from the current folder in host to the dest folder in container
COPY . /home/TestProj

WORKDIR /home/TestProj

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "simple_job_2.py"]
```

Here is how I build these container images:

```
 docker build -t simple_job_1:1.0 .
 docker build -t simple_job_2:1.0 .
```

And here is my docker-compose yaml file:

**simple_compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  job1:
    image: simple_job_1:1.0
  job2:
    image: simple_job_2:1.0
```

Q1) I need to run this compose - say - every 10th minute as a cronjob. How can I achieve it? I know that it is possible to run containers as cronjobs but is it possible to do that with docker compose?

Q2) Is it possible to run the docker-compose as a cronjob in Google Cloud GKE?

Q3) How can I make sure that job2 only starts after job1 completes?

---

ADDENDUM:
Here is an example of cronjob spec for running containers as cronjobs in GKE:

```
# cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: simple-job-cj-1
spec:
  schedule: "0 8 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 100
  suspend: false
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: simple-job-cj-1
            image: simple_job
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

But please note that this is running a given container. By not being an expert in this field, I guess I can define multiple containers under the `containers:` section in the `spec:` above, which probably(?) means I do not need to use docker-compose then?? But if that is the case, how can I make sure that job2 only starts after job1 completes running?

Comment: sure it will work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for your answer. I would though appreciate if you could show how to do that as well, if you have the possibility.. :)

Comment: are you stuck on the cronjob, making or adding it?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I added a 3rd question to my question above and an addendum by providing more information. Do you think you can help me to understand it better with this additional info? If I can list my containers in the cronjob.yaml, how can I make sure that job2 only runs after job1 completes? Since there is this dependency, I thought I probably need to solve this with docker compose but I maybe don't need to...?

Comment: I assume that would be possible to create several cronjob resources using the same container images but different command and args for each job and the use spec.concurrencyPolicy Forbid and spec.startingDeadlineSeconds.

Comment: If you really just need to run two jobs sequentially, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880653/5529712.  Basically you run the first job as an init container.

Comment: For more advanced cases, https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows might work as well